# How do I determine from where UIImagePickerView was presented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have two buttons,`button1` and`button2`. tapping these buttons will present the `UIImagePickerViewController`. In the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` how can I determine which button's action the `UIImagePickerViewController` was presented from?

Comment: Use a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can identify your object using **`Tag`** property, initially assign the tag for your each UIButton, secondary whenever present the `UIImagePickerController` assign the button tag to **UIImagePickerController.view.tag**, for e.g

for e.g

```
 @IBAction func buttonOneClick(_ sender:UIButton) {
    //... code for present the UIImagePickerController
    yourimagePicker.view.tag = sender.tag
}
@IBAction func buttonTwoClick(_ sender:UIButton) {
      //... code for present the UIImagePickerController
       yourimagePicker.view.tag = sender.tag
}
```

or else create the common method for your UIButton

```
 @IBAction func buttonPresentImage(_ sender:UIButton) {
      //... code for present the UIImagePickerController
       yourimagePicker.view.tag = sender.tag
}
```

finally UIImagePickerController delegate method you can identify

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if picker.view.tag == button1.tag {
        // its button1
    } else {
        // its button2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one variable.

```
var selectedButtonTag: Int = 0
```

OnClick of button set the variable like this.

```
    @IBAction func buttonFirstClick(_ sender:UIButton) {
        selectedButtonTag = 0
    }
    @IBAction func buttonSecondClick(_ sender:UIButton) {
        selectedButtonTag = 1
    }
```

In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method you can do like this.

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if selectedButtonTag == 0 {
            print("First button clicked.")
        } else {
            print("Second button clicked.")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don,t use any globle variable to do that,You have to use runtime routine `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` for that:

```
var kAssociatedObject = "associatedObject"
@IBAction func firstButtonAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(picker, &kAssociatedObject, sender, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

}
@IBAction func secondButtonAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(picker, &kAssociatedObject, sender, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

       let sender = objc_getAssociatedObject(picker, &kAssociatedObject) 

      if sender == firstButton {
         //First button selected
      } else if sender == secondButton {
        //second button selected
      }
        //Now you have button object in your delegate method, you can check which button is selected and you also can associate any type of object and get data. This is the best way to attach and get the data from any object


}
```

And also you can use tag property like that:

```
   //set tag
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.view.tag


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    // get tag
    let tagData = picker.view.tag
   // you can handle your condition accordingly
    }
```

Comment: Why do this over a simple property that keeps track of the selected button?